# Typescript local variable inference after if check

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, mapping

I have a question about type inference. Why it doesn't work on a sample below? Error says that return type of `IMapT[T]` is inferred to `T1 & T2` even when there's an explicit if statements on value of `T`. When value of `T` is known as one of enum values, I expect return type to expect `T1` or `T2` interface respectively to the `IMapT` interface.

```js
enum EModule {
  T1 = 0,
  T2 = 1,
}

interface T1 {
  a: number
}
interface T2 {
  b: string
}

interface IMapT {
  [EModule.T1]: T1
  [EModule.T2]: T2
}

function check<T extends EModule> (p: T): IMapT[T] | null {
  if (p === EModule.T1) {
    return {
      a: 10,
    }
  }
  if (p === EModule.T2) {
    return {
      b: '',
    }
  }
  return null
}

const x = check(EModule.T1)
``
```

Comment: The compiler does not narrow `T` by checking `p`, and so it cannot tell that, e.g., `{a: 10}` is assignable to `IMapT[T]`.  You would have to refactor so that it's an actual lookup like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLqv2W) if you want it to compile. See the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: @jcalz As a workaround I did the same but it's strange. I assumed such inference would work as I've seen error `This condition will always return 'true'` multiple times. I'm more interested in why typescript can't understand narrowed down types.

Comment: Checking a value does not imply anything about a generic type parameter , in general, and even in cases where it does, the compiler doesn't do this sort of higher-order logic.  It isn't true that `p === EModule.T1` then `T` is `EModule.T1`.   It could be that `T` is the full `EModule` union.  Everyone agrees that *sometihng* should be done here, but it's not obvious what or how. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014 for one suggestion to address this.

Comment: @jcalz "It could be that T is the full EModule union" that's exactly what I was thinking all the times working with enums, really confusing. Thanks for sharing the issue and thanks for the feedback!